# I can only use T4 GPU for one hour even If I am Colab Pro user

Tags: google-colaboratory

I trained the model for one hour and got disconnected from the system and then Colab show "You can not connect to the GPU backend". By the way I am Colab Pro user for three months, and this months I am facing with this problem for the first time.

I stuck with this problem about 1 weeks. I tried to connect the GPU at the same time (10 AM. GMT+7) everyday, I trained the model for one hour and got disconnected from the system that was not my expected. for two months ago I can open the notebook and run the model for 6 hours or 8 hours but now I can not do that anymore.

How can I fix this problem or I should upgrade to Colab Pro+?

Answer (score 0):

You can't fix it, Google is pulling some hot garbage. I recommend absolutely not paying them more money until this is solved on their end.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).